# Sub or Function not Defined MS Access SendEmailFromOutlook

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hey there i am sure this will be a really quick fix and when someone points it out to me i'll think seriously i didn't see that! But i've been trying to get this function called "SendEmailWithOutlook" from another sub and it's just not working.

```
If Not (CountriesFilter.EOF And CountriesFilter.BOF) Then
    CountriesFilter.MoveFirst
    Do Until CountriesFilter.EOF = True
        If Not (EmailCountry.EOF And EmailCountry.BOF) Then
            EmailCountry.MoveFirst
            Do Until EmailCountry.EOF = True
                If EmailCountry!Country = CountriesFilter!Country Then
                    Country = CountriesFilter!Country
                    Email = EmailCountry!EmailEmail

                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "BadUsers"
                    Set qdfsCountry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("BadUsersqry")
                    qdfsCountry!WhatCountry = Country
                    qdfsCountry.Execute
                    Set qdfsCountry = Nothing

                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "OkayUsers"
                    Set qdfsCountry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("OkayUsersqry")
                    qdfsCountry!WhatCountry = Country
                    qdfsCountry.Execute
                    Set qdfsCountry = Nothing

                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "GoodUsers"
                    Set qdfsCountry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("GoodUsersqry")
                    qdfsCountry!WhatCountry = Country
                    qdfsCountry.Execute
                    Set qdfsCountry = Nothing

                    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, 
"BadUsers", "L:\WeeklyUserActivity\WeeklyUserBreakDown" & Country & ".xlsx", 
True, "BadUsers"
                    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, 
"OkayUsers", "L:\WeeklyUserActivity\WeeklyUserBreakDown" & Country & 
".xlsx", True, "OkayUsers"
                    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, 
"GoodUsers", "L:\WeeklyUserActivity\WeeklyUserBreakDown" & Country & 
".xlsx", True, "GoodUsers"

                    Main 
"L:\WeeklyUserActivity\WeeklyUserBreakDown" & Country & ".xlsx"
                    ***Call SendEmailWithOutlook***
                End If
                Email = ""
                EmailCountry.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        Country = ""
        CountriesFilter.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

And here is the function it is calling

```
Public Function SendEmailWithOutlook()
Dim sentfrom As String
Dim toemail As String
Dim subjectemail As String

sentfrom = "An EMAIL"
  ' Define app variable and get Outlook using the "New" keyword
  Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
  Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem ' An Outlook Mail item
  'Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments

  ' Create a new email object
  Set MItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  'Set myattachments = MItem.Attachments
  ' Add the To/Subject/Body to the message and display the message
  With MItem
    .To = Email
    .Subject = "WeeklyUserBreakDown"
    .Body = "Automated Email. Please Find your weekly user Breakdown 
  Spreadsheet attachted"
    .Attachments.Add ("L:\WeeklyUserActivity\WeeklyUserBreakDown" & Country 
  & ".xlsx")
    .Send       ' Send the message immediately
  End With
  Exit Function
  email_error:
  MsgBox "An Error was encountered. " & vbCrLf & "The error message is: " & 
  Err.Description
  Resume Error_out
  Error_out:
  ' Release all object variables
  Set MItem = Nothing
  Set olApp = Nothing
  End Function
```

That function is a module so should be able to call it. But still no idea why i can't call it.

Comment: Do you have [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module? Does your code compile?

Comment: The error may be in `SendEmailWithOutlook`. While you have an error handler there, there is no `On Error Goto` in there.

Comment: "That function is a module" - you mean *in* a module? What type of module? If it's in a *class module*, then you can't invoke it like this. FWIW `Call` keyword is redundant/obsolete, and a `Function` should return a value.

Comment: 'Does not work' means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: Is `WeeklyUserBreakDown` a folder or part of the spreadsheet name? If it's a folder, need a \

Comment: Why are you showing the function call within `***`?? Just to get our attention? Should not post code annotated like that. What is `Main`?

Comment: Might want to correct spelling of `attachted` to `attached`.

Comment: Hey sorry to everyone. Didn't realise i had done quite that much wrong.
First of all the Function is in a Class Module. With doesn't work i mean when i try to run the code doesnt compile it immediately highlights "SendEmailWithOutlook" and gives the error "Sub or Function not defined. To June7 this is what that bit would look like so i dont think it needs another \ and yes the * was just to draw attention to the section i'll keep that in mind for next time.  "L:\WeeklyUserActivity\WeeklyUserBreakDownde-DE.xlsx"

To Andrea at the top of the main Module where most of the code executes:

Comment: Option Compare Database is that where you'd want me to to put option explicit? That section is in the Modules Folder. So not a class Module.

Comment: I think i have managed to fix the issue i moved it to just the Modules folder and the program can now compiles and runs Thank you to everyone who put time and effort into helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have managed to fix the issue i moved the function to just the Modules folder(Out of the class module folder) and the program can now compiles and runs Thank you to everyone who put time and effort into helping me.

Comment: perhaps you could delete your question ?

Comment: Where can i do that?